# How to format lists in a vertical and horizontal way in Python 3x?

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a new encrypting system. I want to horizontally and vertically format a list. for education
for example

```
l1=[A,B,C,£,D,E,F,£,G,H,I...,£,W,X,Y,Z]#(continues like phone keyboard)
```

I want it to make a new  column when it sees "£"
Some of the columns contain 4 letters
I want to format it like:

```
A D G     W
B E H ... X
C F I     Y
          Z
```

It will do this later:
İf we want it to write "OMG":

```
M M G       . * *
N N H ----> . . .
O O I       * . .
```

Comment: Use vectors from numpy as you can rotate a vector using transposition.

Comment: Is this just for education? If not, "I'm trying to develop a new encrypting system" is a horrendous red flag and you will fail.

Comment: Will you always have two lists?

Comment: @roganjosh it is for education

Answer (score 2):

To format the lists, you can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
import itertools
l1=['A','B','C']
l2=['D','E','F','G']
new_l = '\n'.join(' '.join(i) for i in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=' '))
print(new_l)
```

Output:

```
A D
B E
C F
  G
```

Edit: you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
l1=['A','B','C','£','D','E','F','£','G','H','I','£','W','X','Y','Z']
new_l = zip(*[list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(l1, key=lambda x:x != '£') if a])
final_l = '\n'.join(' '.join(b) for b in new_l)
```

Output:

```
A D G W
B E H X
C F I Y
```

Comment: im sorry but i chanced question in the way i want to code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
l1=['A','B','C'] 
l2=['D','E','F','G'] 

for first, last in list(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=' ')): 
    print(first, last)
```

output

```
A D
B E
C F
  G
```

Comment: im soo sorry but i chanced the way i code for this project soooorry